# Counting unique numbers from int array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to build and array where the user enters numbers.  Then at the end the program outputs a list of the entered numbers along side the amount of times each individual number was entered.

Currently I have:

```
package arraypractice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entry {

private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public void userInput(){    
System.out.println("Please tell me the amount of numbers you will be $ entering: ");
        int [] arr = new int[scan.nextInt()];
         for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++) {
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            int x = scan.nextInt();
            arr[i]= x;
            break;
            }
        }
         for(int i:arr){System.out.println(i + " occurs"); 
        }
} 



}
```

For example this outputs:

```
run:
Please tell me the amount of numbers you will be $ entering: 
2
Please enter a number: 
25
Please enter a number: 
21
25 occurs
21 occurs
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

In a perfect world I would like to output to look like this:

```
run:
Please tell me the amount of numbers you will be $ entering: 
2
Please enter a number: 
25
Please enter a number: 
21
   Number      Times Entered
    25    occurs   1
    21    occurs   1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

I am not sure how to implement this.  A second array?  If so how?  Also is there a way I can get the headings Number and Times Entered?

You are not seeing a main method because it is in another class that instantiates this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't under the post you linked and it doesn't seem to answer my question.  It is very generic and I can not apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get a heading you just put a `println()` method before you run the `for` loop to print out the `array`.

It seems like you want to format the print out. To do that you would need to use

```
printf("%6d%10s%6d", i, "occurs", array[i])
```

That's the general idea.